# why can't hidden single button form the ExtJs3 buttongroup?

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have four button inside the buttongroup when i hide button all button hide with buttongroup. Is this bug ExtJs3 or something i did worng?

This what i used for hide button

```
var theSameButton = Ext.getCmp('my_button_id');
theSameButton.hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think "my_button_id" is your button group id. can you post your code?
if u want only one button hide try below code.

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
var Window = new Ext.Window(
            {
                width : 340,
                height : 150,
                iconCls : 'upload',
                defaults : {
                    bodyStyle : 'padding:0px'
                },
                items : [{
        xtype: 'buttongroup',
        id:'buttonGrp',
        items: [{
            text: 'Paste',id:'button1',handler : function(){ Ext.getCmp('button2').hide();}
        },{
            text: 'Copy',id:'button2'
        },{
            text: 'Format',id:'button3'
        }]
    } ]
            });
    Window.show();
});
```

Comment: no that is my one of button id. i can't find good document for how to disable single button in the button group

Comment: then can you provide your buttongroup code? so only i can help.

Comment: Add to your groupButton config: **hidden : false,** and try again. Default value is false too, but without paste your code...